# Using SignalR 2x in unity3d

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, signalr, signalr.client

I want to use SignalR to communicate between Unity Game and a server on the same machine.
I tried `Nivot,SignalR.Client.Net35` but it gives me the following error:

```
Could not install package 'Nivot.SignalR.Client.Net35 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets      '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Subset v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

**First Question:**
Why am I getting this error? both the package and unity are using .Net 3.5, thus, should be compatible.

---

I tried to skip that library and used [SignalR.Client.20](https://github.com/jenyayel/SignalR.Client.20) instead; it seems to import correctly, but uses Protocol 1.2, and I cannot rollback my server to 1.x because my universal app client is on 2.x

**Second Question:** is there a .net SignalR 2.x library I can use in unity3d?

**Third Question:** unity3d seems to use a variation of Javascript called [Unityscript](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript), how can I use Javascript [SignalRJs](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js%22%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%3C/script%3E%20%3Cscript%20src=%22Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js%22%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%3C/script%3E) libraries inside it?

**TL;DR:** Can I get any answer on how to run SignalR client  2.x on Unity3D?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question:** while Unity claims to use Mono .Net 3.5, it's a slightly modified framework and isn't exactly the same as vanilla .net 3.5

**Second Question:** So SignalR is backward compatible, and the protocol 1.x and 2.x were compatible. I ended up using [SignalR.Client2.00](https://github.com/jenyayel/SignalR.Client.20). I got a code sample from a [german blog](http://codefest.at/post/2014/09/11/SignalR-und-Unity-in-euren-Multiplayer-Indie-Games.aspx)

I still did not figure out the **third Question**

Comment: Did you have to change any unity settings around networking? In Unity 5.1f1 using SignalR.Client2.00 it hangs because it can't see the hub (open bug on github). However when I create a standalone c# console project it connects fine.

Comment: I have not changed any settings